# Why is twice ddifferential of running maximum zero?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have saw the following statement in my notes. But I cannot see it clearly, if someone could explain?

Consider an Itô process given by
$$
\mathrm{d} Z_{t}=a_{t} \mathrm{~d} t+b_{t} \mathrm{~d} W_{t},
$$
for some processes $a, b$ such that the two integrals associated with this expression are well-defined. Also, consider the running maximum and running minimum processes $\bar{Z}$ and $\underline{Z}$, which are defined by
$$
\bar{Z}_{t}=\max _{u \in[0, t]} Z_{u} \quad \text { and } \quad \underline{Z}_{t}=\min _{u \in[0, t]} Z_{u}
$$

which imply that,
$$
\left(\mathrm{d} \bar{Z}_{t}\right)^{2}=\left(\mathrm{d} \underline{Z}_{t}\right)^{2}=\mathrm{d} \bar{Z}_{t} \mathrm{~d} \underline{Z}_{t}=\mathrm{d} \bar{Z}_{t} \mathrm{~d} t=\mathrm{d} \underline{Z}_{t} \mathrm{~d} t=\mathrm{d} \bar{Z}_{t} \mathrm{~d} W_{t}=\mathrm{d} \underline{Z}_{t} \mathrm{~d} W_{t}=0.
$$

Comment: Isn't there an ambiguity of notation with $Z$ and the running minimum process depending on $Z$ ?

Comment: @SacAndSac Thank you for the comment, I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\bar Z_t$ is an increasing process, and so it has finite variation until it hits $\infty$.  Since the integrals are well-defined, $Z_t < \infty$ for all $t$ and so $\bar Z_t$ has finite variation.  Similarly, $\underline{Z}_t$ is a decreasing process and hence also has finite variation.  Since the quadratic variation of any process of finite variation is $0$, the claims follow.

To see that any finite increasing process $X$ has finite variation on any interval $[0,t]$, observe that for any partition of the interval we have \begin{align*} \sum |X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i}| = \sum (X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i}) = X_t - X_0 <\infty
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you let me know why increasing processes have finite variations?

Comment: @David I added the proof to the answer